# Error When Issuing `go install`

Tags: go

I'm in my go root path and I get error the following errors when I perform the `go install` command...

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/bin/src/fmt (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rbtlong/go/src/fmt (from $GOPATH)
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "io/ioutil" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/bin/src/io/ioutil (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rbtlong/go/src/io/ioutil (from $GOPATH)
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "net/http" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/bin/src/net/http (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rbtlong/go/src/net/http (from $GOPATH)
package rbtlong.com
    imports runtime: cannot find package "runtime" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/bin/src/runtime (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rbtlong/go/src/runtime (from $GOPATH)
```

I have tried unsetting the GOROOT, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does it print when you run `echo $GOROOT` and `go env GOROOT`?  Also, what's the output from `which go`?

Comment: echo $GOROOT
/usr/lib/go-1.6/bin

Comment: go env GOROOT
/usr/lib/go-1.6/bin

Comment: which go
/usr/bin/go

Comment: Ok, so it's all in the same location.  Is there a `src/` directory under `/usr/lib/go-1.6/bin`?  If you installed Go there initially, there _should_ be.

Comment: there isn't one. only go and gofmt

Comment: Btw, you can unset $GOROOT using `unset GOROOT`, but like the export command in the first place, this only applies to the current terminal session.

Comment: Sounds like your go install is all sorts of mucked up.  Try unsetting GOROOT, then running `go env GOROOT` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130739/discussion-between-kaedys-and-rbtlong).

Comment: i tried this. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, the definition was defined in $HOME/.bashrc after removing the definition for GOPATH and GOROOT, then manually removing the folder at  /usr/lib/go-1.6 then reinstalling it using the instructions here https://golang.org/doc/install#install then setting the PATH and GOPATH by editing **$HOME/.profile**:

> PATH="[...]:/usr/local/go/bin[...]"
>
> export GOPATH="$HOME/go"

it appears to be working now...

Answer (score 2):

Per discussion, it sounds like your install is a bit mucked up.  Reinstalling Go seems to be the best option.

For others investigating GOROOT issues, the first step is almost always going to be to **unset GOROOT**.  In most cases, [GOROOT is not needed](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really), and tends to muck up the works.

Another option for managing your Go installs more easily (and largely automagically), which also gives a homebrew-like version swapping capability and a containerization similar to virtualenv for Python or rvm for Ruby, is to use [GVM](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm).

Answer (score 0):

Before doing `go install` check for the Go version and Go path, if these are correct you won't get any error.

Please, install Go latest version from the official website and re-try once.